# reset previously choose an option

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

need to reset the choice previusly made when 0 is selected,

if i choose 3, 3 options appear,
what i need is that after that if i choose another option and it updates the options displayed

for example:
select 4 (4 slots open)
after
select 2 (closes the 4 open slots and open 2 new slots)

this is a select box(drop) and depending on my selection it shows a number of options(optionsslot), i need that if a user select(drop) another number of options update the options(optionsslot) shown

```
lbl = Label(frmConf, width="16", text="Number of Slots to Test:", justify=LEFT, anchor="w").grid(row=8, column=3, pady=2)

    options = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', ]

    clicked = StringVar()
    clicked.set(options[0])

    def slotstypes(clicked):
        
        i = int(0)
        a = int(clicked)
        while i < a:
            lbl = Label(frmConf, width="16", text="Slot"+str(i+1)+":", justify=LEFT, anchor="w").grid(row=(9+i), column=3, pady=2)

            optionsslot = ['Select', 'opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3',]

            clickedslot = StringVar()
            clickedslot.set(optionsslot[0])

            dropslot = OptionMenu(frmConf, clickedslot, *optionsslot).grid(row=(9+i), column=4, pady=2)
            i += 1

    drop = OptionMenu(frmConf, clicked, *options, command=slotstypes).grid(row=8, column=4, pady=2)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question about this?

Comment: @mkrieger1 this is a select box(drop) and depending on my selection it shows a number of options(optionsslot), i need that if a user select(drop) another number of options update the options(optionsslot) shown

Comment: That is a requirement, not a question. Was there a particular problem when you tried to implement that? What was it?

Comment: @mkrieger1 the question is how can i do it? was thinking on creating a function but since the labels are not identified i can do a hide on then. was thinking on this drop.grid_forget() but cant seem to implement it